# i`m getting the 400 response error in react.js i know the backendd is ok but the client side i am not sure i am not fimiliar with react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I can't create a class and I don't know why. I am not familiar with react so much.

I am learning from this project I set for my self so please help I am working on it for 2 days and i don't know why this is happening.

#### this is my view i know this one is working

```
 class CreateClassRoomView(APIView):

        serializer_class = CreateClassRoomSerializer
    
    
        def post(self, request, format=None):
    
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                ostad = request.data['ostad.name']
                lesson = request.data['lesson.name']
                day = request.data.get('day')
    
                lesson_obj = Lesson.objects.get(name=lesson)
                master_obj = Master.objects.get(name=ostad)
    
    
    
                room = ClassRoom.objects.create(
                    ostad=master_obj,
                    lesson=lesson_obj,
                    day=day
                )
                room.save()
                return Response(CreateClassRoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(
                    {
                        'message': "This is problem"
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
```

#### serializer

```
 from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import (ClassRoom, Lesson, Master)



class StringSerializer(serializers.StringRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        return value

class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson  
        fields = ( 
            'name',
        )

class MasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = (
            'name',
        )


class ClassRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lesson = LessonSerializer()
    ostad = MasterSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ClassRoom
        fields = (
            'id','user',
            'code','image',
            'ostad', 'lesson',
            'slug', 'deadline', 'day'
        )

       

class DetailClassRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lesson = LessonSerializer()
    ostad = MasterSerializer()

    
    class Meta:
        model = ClassRoom
        fields = (
            'code','image',
            'ostad', 'lesson',
            'slug', 'deadline', 'day'
        )

class CreateClassRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lesson = LessonSerializer(many=False)
    ostad = MasterSerializer(many=False)


    class Meta:
        model = ClassRoom
        fields = (
            'code',
            'ostad', 'lesson',
            'day',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('code',)
```

#### models

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save 

import string
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6
    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if ClassRoom.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break
    return code
    


class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=generate_unique_code, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True,
        upload_to="classes/"
        
    )
    ostad = models.ForeignKey('Master', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="reza")
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lesson', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="reza")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Answer',related_name='answered',
        blank=True
    )
    day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


def pre_save_slug_ref_code(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # if not created:
    instance.slug = instance.code
    if not instance.code:
        day = instance.day
        time = timedelta(days=day)
        deadline = instance.date + time
        instance.deadline = deadline
        

pre_save.connect(pre_save_slug_ref_code, sender=ClassRoom)


class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Master(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Answer(models.Model):
    # username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_answer = models.ImageField(upload_to='answers/')
    question = models.ForeignKey('ClassRoom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # liked = models.ManyToManyField(
    #     User, related_name='liked',
    #     blank=True
    # )
```

#### This is a component i have problem with

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

import ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class CreateClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            lesson: [
                {
                    name: "",
                },
            ],
            master: [
                {
                    name: "",
                },
            ],
            day: 1,
            products: {
                id: null,
                lesson: {
                    name: "",
                },
                master: {
                    name: "",
                },
                day: 0,
            },
        };

        this.handelDay = this.handelDay.bind(this);
        this.handelLesson = this.handelLesson.bind(this);
        this.handelOstad = this.handelOstad.bind(this);
        this.getMaster = this.getMaster.bind(this);
        this.getLesson = this.getLesson.bind(this);
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
        this.handelCreate = this.handelCreate.bind(this);
        this.handelRoomButtonPressed = this.handelRoomButtonPressed.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMaster();
        this.getLesson();
        this.fetchData();
    }

    getMaster() {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/master/")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    master: data,
                });
            });
    }

    getLesson() {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lesson/")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    lesson: data,
                });
            });
    }

    fetchData() {
        console.log("fetchiing");
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
        fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: data,
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Do something for an error here
                console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
            });
    }

    getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    handelOstad(e) {
        this.setState({
            products: {
                ...this.state.products,
                master: e.target.value,
            },
        });
    }

    handelLesson(e) {
        this.setState({
            products: {
                ...this.state.products,
                lesson: e.target.value,
            },
        });
    }

    handelDay(e) {
        // console.log("day", e.target.name);
        this.setState({
            products: {
                ...this.state.products,
                day: e.target.value,
            },
        });
    }
```

#### i wrote two method but none of them work i seperate this to see better this is countinue of code above

```
handelRoomButtonPressed(e) {
            console.log("item", this.state.products);
            e.preventDefault();
            var csrftoken = this.getCookie("csrftoken");
    
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-class";
            try {
                fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json",
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.products),
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.fetchData();
                        this.setState({
                            products: {
                                id: null,
                                lesson: {
                                    name: "",
                                },
                                master: {
                                    name: "",
                                },
                                day: 0,
                            },
                        });
                    })
                    .then((data) => console.log(data));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("catch");
            }
        }
    
        handelCreate(e) {
            console.log("item bad", this.state.products);
            e.preventDefault();
            var csrftoken = this.getCookie("csrftoken");
    
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-class";
    
            fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state.products),
            }).then((res) => {
                res.json();
                this.fetchData();
            });
        }

    render() {
        // console.log("pros", this.state.products);
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handelCreate}>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Ostad</Form.Label>

                    <Form.Control
                        as="select"
                        onChange={this.handelOstad}
                        value={this.state.products.master.name}
                    >
                        {this.state.master.map(function (master, index) {
                            return <option key={index}>{master.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <br />
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Lesson</Form.Label>

                    <Form.Control
                        as="select"
                        onChange={this.handelLesson}
                        value={this.state.products.lesson.name}
                    >
                        {this.state.lesson.map(function (lesson, index) {
                            return <option key={index}>{lesson.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <br />
                {/* <Form.Group>

                    <Form.File id="exampleFormControlFile1" label="image file "  onChange={this.handelChange}/>
                </Form.Group>

                    <br /> */}
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>days</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="day"
                        onChange={this.handelDay}
                        value={this.state.products.day}
                    />
                    <Button onSubmit={this.handelCreate } type="submit">submit</Button>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default CreateClass;
```

Comment: Hello @reza izadijahromi can you provide what is  error in you browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are missing to mount the component somewhere on an actual HTML page.
A root React component needs to be injected on an **already existing** DOM node, for that you need to use `ReactDOM`.
For a Django application there are 2 ways you can do this:

1. Use a Django template to serve the HTML where the react component will be mounted later on.

You can do this by adding a function that renders the given template (I'm assuming an app

```py
# ./myapp/views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')
```

Then your HTML file can look something like this:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My app with React</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- React will load here -->
</div>
</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "myapp/main.js" %}"></script>
</html>
```

Then you simply mount your component

```js
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import MyComponent from 'path/to/my/component'

const root = document.getElementById("app")
render(<MyComponent />, root);
```

2. Use a boilerplate like `create-react-app`

You can do the 'heavy-lifting' through `create-react-app` which will work out of the box. It takes care of a lot things for you so you can focus more on development; this comes with the implied cost of it being somewhat of a 'black box' as well as some additional management because your frontend app will be 'served' by webpack behind the scenes (by default on port 3000) which you then may need to reconcile later on by defining a proxy on your package.json or even with a reverse-proxy such as nginx.

Here are some more in-depth tutorials for the alternatives above:

1. React + Django template tutorial: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/#django-and-react-together
2. React + Django create-react-app tutorial:
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react